# Mail plugin configuration using Grails 3

Tags: email, grails-3.0

I have a problem when I try to use the mail plugin in grails. The ones I've searched in Google are mainly for Grails version 2 mail plugin.

I have tried to setup using

`compile 'org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC6'`
in my buildConfig.groovy

and

```
sendMail {
        to "xxxxxx@gmail.com"
        from "........@yahoo.com"
        subject "This is a test mail"
        text "Hello, This is a test mail, how are you?"
    }
```

in one of my controllers functions

When I try to run it, MailConnectException occurred. Have I missed any mail plugin configurations for grails 3 ? or do i have to add something into application.groovy like grails 2 in this site http://grails.asia/grails-mail-plugin-example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself in fact I need to put the mail configuration into application.groovy like in grails 2. And the MailConnectionException is due to high security in Email, therefore, what I did was to set it to allow apps to connect to mail. This is available in security options of Mail system.